If $a,b,c≥0$ prove the inequality $(a+b+c)³+(a+b)³ ≥ ab[27c+4(a+b)]$ When does equality holds?
If $a,b,c≥0$ prove the inequality
$(a+b+c)³+(a+b)³ ≥ ab[27c+4(a+b)]$
When does equality holds?
I easily proved this inequality using the AM-GM inequality.
We are given the inequality:
$$(a+b+c)^3 + (a+b)^3 \geq ab[27c + 4(a+b)]$$
where $a, b, c \geq 0$. I have to prove this inequality and determine when equality holds.
Proof using AM-GM inequality:
By the AM-GM inequality, we have:
$$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$$
Squaring both sides:
$$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 \geq ab$$
Thus,
$$\frac{(a+b)^2}{4} \geq ab$$
$$(a+b)^2\geq 4ab$$
Now multiply both sides by $(a+b)$:
$$ (a+b)^3 \geq 4ab(a+b) \quad \text{(1)}$$
Next, we apply the AM-GM inequality again to $(a+b+c)$. By AM-GM:
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$
Cubing both sides:
$$\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3 \geq abc$$
This simplifies to:
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{27} \geq abc$$
Multiplying both sides by 27:
$$(a+b+c)^3 \geq 27abc \quad \text{(2)}$$
Adding (1) and (2):
$$(a+b)^3 + (a+b+c)^3 \geq 4ab(a+b) + 27abc$$
Thus, we have:
$$(a+b+c)^3 + (a+b)^3 \geq ab[4(a+b) + 27c]$$
which is the desired inequality.
But I have no idea on how to solve the second part of this question.

Observe that if a = b = c the equality holds.

Recall that$$\frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n}{n} = \sqrt[n]{x_1\ldots x_n}$$if and only if $x_1 = \ldots = x_n$. Also, if $a \le b$, $c \le d$, and $a + c = b + d$, then $a = b$ and $c = d$. Try using these facts to reverse engineer your inequality proof for the equality case.

Can you post your "easily proved" solution? From there, you should be able to easily state the equality conditions to determine the equality case (which is just $a=b=c$).

Yes I can do that

Let us suppose that
$$(a+b+c)^3 + (a+b)^3 = ab(4(a+b) + 27c). \tag{3}$$
We got the inequality by adding $(1)$ and $(2)$. What would happen if $(1)$ or $(2)$ were a strict inequality? Let's say $(1)$ was a strict inequality, for starters. That is,
$$(a+b)^3 > 4ab(a+b).$$
Then, adding $(a + b + c)^3$ to both sides, we obtain
$$(a+b)^3 + (a + b + c)^3 > 4ab(a+b) + (a + b + c)^3. \tag{4}$$
Adding $4ab(a + b)$ to both sides of $(2)$, we obtain
$$4ab(a+b) + (a + b + c)^3 \ge 4ab(a+b) + 27abc. \tag{5}$$
So, in total, combining $(4)$ and $(5)$, we obtain
$$(a+b)^3 + (a + b + c)^3 > 4ab(a+b) + 27abc,$$
which directly contradicts $(3)$. So, $(1)$ cannot be a strict inequality. A similar argument, or simply subtracting $(1)$ with equality from $(3)$, tells us that $(2)$ must also achieve equality. That is, we may now assume
\begin{align*}
(a + b + c)^3 &= 27abc, \tag{6} \\
(a + b)^3 &= 4ab(a + b). \tag{7}
\end{align*}
Next, I want to tweak $(7)$ by dividing by $a + b$. This is possible in most situations, however if $a + b = 0$, then we are in trouble. So, let us consider, now, what happens if $a + b = 0$? Given $a, b \ge 0$, we must have $a = b = 0$. Plugging this into $(6)$, we obtain $c^3 = 0$, which implies $c = 0$. Thus, in this case, the only solution is $a = b = c = 0$.
Otherwise, we obtain an equivalent equation:
$$(a + b)^2 = 4ab.$$
Clearly this equation, and equation $(6)$ respectively, may be written in the equivalent form:
\begin{align*}
\frac{a + b}{2} &= \sqrt{ab} \\
\frac{a + b + c}{3} &= \sqrt[3]{abc}.
\end{align*}
That is, both equations are the result of equality in the AGM inequality. The AGM is typically stated with an equality condition: the arithmetic mean of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is equal to its geometric mean if and only if $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_n$. So, applying this to the above equations (the latter equation in particular), we see $a = b = c$.
So, collecting our two cases, we must have $a = b = c$. And quick verification shows that the $a = b = c$ cases produce equality. So, equality happens if and only if $a = b = c$.

Note how I essentially worked through your argument, but backwards. I started with the assumption of equality, and worked backwards to discover that equality held at most of the previous steps too. It was only when I got back to the AGM inequality that I needed to rely on some kind of theorem, but (as is common with these fundimental inequalities) the equality condition is baked into the theorem statement of the AGM inequality.
So, my advice is, when trying to figure out an equality condition, work backwards!
